# NullPointerException trying to get index.jsp set up

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

**EDIT:** I was able to fix the problem by renaming `index.jsp` to `hi.jsp`. Anyone have an idea of why I'm getting a problem with the file name?

**PROBLEM:**
I wrote the backend component of a webapp using Java/Spring and hooked it up to Tomcat through Spring annotations:

```
@Controller
public class WorkerSubmitterController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/start"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> start() throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Started", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I'm configuring servlets like this:

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.scan("com.myProject.someName");

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        Set<String> mappingConflicts = dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

This works fine when I go to `localhost:8080/start`

However, now I'm trying to write the frontend by getting `index.jsp` working. I created a `index.jsp` file under `/webapp/WEB-INF/` with the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
```

I added a `web.xml` file:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I visit `localhost:8080/home`
I get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /home. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

and the server side shows:

```
2013-10-08 20:27:31.652:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/home
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:171)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:474)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss a step to get .jsp pages working? Is `index.jsp` incorrect? I've tried modifying `index.jsp` to just be `hello` and the same error pops up. Also, I've tried moving the `index.jsp` file to find the source of the problem, and the error disappears, but then I get

```
Oct 08, 2013 9:58:38 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet serviceJspFile
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "%2FUsers%2FuserName%2Fpersonal%2Friver%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fwebapp%2FWEB-INF%2Findex.jsp" not found
```

So I guess the problem is related to my JSP file.

Comment: It seems to be a warning, not an error. You didn't declare encoding of the file?

Comment: I used to have <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> at the top of index.jsp, but it still gave me the same error

Comment: I've also tried adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
      content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a JSP that is in the `WEB-INF` directory, which is obviously inaccessible. And you are trying to access it from the root, that's why you get the error `HTTP ERROR 404`

`However, now I'm trying to write the frontend by getting index.jsp working. I created a index.jsp file under /webapp/WEB-INF/ with the following:...`

Try moving the JSP outside the `WEB-INF` folder into the root of your application.

Comment: @Popcorn As an additional information. It is **also** a wide-spread security practice (if you need it, of course) to intentionally put JSP files inside WEB-INF to prevent direct access from the client brouser. In this case, you should use some servlet that will be accessed first when a request is sent to the specified URL, and in that servlet you use a [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) to forward to the desired JSP, like `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);`